# Episode splitting and removing overlap

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am interested in including treatment as a time varying covariate in my Cox regression models. To do this, I 'simply' have to split each patients episode in treatment intervals. I have issues arranging my treatment data in clean intervals. Each patient can have multiple treatments (A/B/..), which might be partly overlapping. I'd like to consider overlapping treatment as a separate category (A/B/AB).

My treatment data comes in as:

```
   df <- structure(list(Pt = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    start = c(30L, 35L, 60L, 80L, 120L, 5L, 15L, 45L, 65L, 80L
    ), stop = c(45L, 100L, 90L, 95L, 150L, 20L, 35L, 55L, 100L, 
    90L), tx = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Pt", 
"start", "stop", "tx"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

> df
   Pt start stop tx
1   1    30   45  A
2   1    35  100  B
3   1    60   90  A
4   1    80   95  A
5   1   120  150  B
6   2     5   20  A
7   2    15   35  B
8   2    45   55  B
9   2    65  100  A
10  2    80   90  B
```

And what I would like to get is:

```
> result
   Pt start stop   tx
1   1     0   30 None
2   1    30   35    A
3   1    35   45   AB
4   1    45   60    B
5   1    60   95   AB
6   1    95  100    B
7   1   100  120 None
8   1   120  150    B
9   2     0    5 None
10  2     5   15    A
11  2    15   20   AB
12  2    20   35    B
13  2    35   45 None
14  2    45   55    B
15  2    55   65 None
16  2    65   80    A
17  2    80   90   AB
18  2    90  100    A
```

Please note that:

- The same treatment might have overlapping intervals (see pt 1, Tx A
  from 60-90 and from 80-95).
- All patients start at time=0.
- Periods of no-treatment are included.
- I have ~200k pts.

EDIT:
I have created an ugly solution using for-loops. I'm not sure if this will run on my large data set, but at least it does this example well. Ideas for speeding up welcome!

```
# Create empty data.frame for results
results <- data.frame(Pt=c(), start=c(), stop=c(), tx=c()) 


for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Pt))){   # Loop over patients
  pt <- subset(df, Pt == unique(df$Pt)[i])

  out <- data.frame(day = c(1:max(pt$stop))) # Create df (1 row for each day; pt specific) which will be filled with treatment info below

  # Loop over treatments (allows for patient's treatments to differ)
  for(t in 1:length(unique(pt$tx))){  
    name <- as.character(unique(pt$tx)[t])
    out[[name]] <- NA
    out[[name]][unique(eval(parse(text=paste0("c(",paste(pt$start[pt$tx == unique(pt$tx)[t]], pt$stop[pt$tx == unique(pt$tx)[t]], sep=":", collapse=","), ")"))))] <- name
  }

  out[is.na(out)==T] <- "" # Remove NA
  out$tx <- do.call(paste, c(out[-1], sep=""))  # Concatenate treatment columns
  out$tx[out$tx ==""] <- "None"

  out  # Check

  # Now compact the tx as intervals
  starting.points = c(0,1+which(diff(as.numeric(as.factor(out$tx)))!=0))
  stopping.points = c(starting.points[-1], dim(out)[1])
  txs             = out$tx[c(1, starting.points[-1])]

  # And write to the general 'results' dataframe
  results <- rbind(results, data.frame(Pt=rep(unique(df$Pt)[i], length(txs)), start=starting.points, stop=stopping.points, tx=txs))
}
results

> results
   Pt start stop   tx
1   1     0   30 None
2   1    30   35    A
3   1    35   46   AB
4   1    46   60    B
5   1    60   96   AB
6   1    96  101    B
7   1   101  120 None
8   1   120  150    B
9   2     0    5 None
10  2     5   15    A
11  2    15   21   AB
12  2    21   36    B
13  2    36   45 None
14  2    45   56    B
15  2    56   65 None
16  2    65   80    A
17  2    80   91   AB
18  2    91  100    A
```

Comment: data: `d <- read.table(textConnection("   Pt start stop tx
1   1    30   45  A
2   1    35  100  B
3   1    60   90  A
4   1    80   95  A
5   1   120  150  B
6   2     5   20  A
7   2    15   35  B
8   2    45   55  B
9   2    65  100  A
10  2    80   90  B"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Sorry Jacob, I am unsure what your comment refers to. Did a part of your comment got cut off?

Comment: I'm just trying to make it easy for other people who want to answer your question to load that data.  It is a tricky question!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is a tricky one!

Comment: The post is on hold. I am not sure how to narrow it down further. I provided an example. It should be useful for anyone who wants to include time varying covariates in their analysis (hence 'episode splitting' in the title).